# Order results by "Best Match" SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-like

I'm working on a project which requires the user to search for certain categories of products. The products have tags such as: T-shirt, Jumper, hat and I am currently displaying the results ordered by the amount of likes. Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE keywords LIKE '%$query%' 
ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 50;
```

But the issue is that if let's say someone searched "hat" but a more popular word was "chatterbox" in the database, it would come up with that first because it has more likes.

So to put it in pseudo code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE keywords LIKE '%$query%' 
ORDER BY "BEST MATCH" LIMIT 50;
```

and the result would ideally be:

2 results:
**Hat**: 26 likes, 
C**hat**terbox: 234 likes,

Instead of:

2 results:
C**hat**terbox : 234 likes, 
**Hat**: 26 likes,

So is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just as a hint: For this job with pure databases you might reach limitations very quickly. Even if you find that "hat" should appear first (which is absolutely correct) you might also find that "hats" should appear before "chatterbox". If this is what you want, you might think about the term "relevance" and have a look at search engines that are especially made for this kind of job.

Comment: As a side note, be aware that your SQL query is not protected against SQL-injection attacks. Use a bind param instead of string interpolation.

Comment: @at54321 Yes thank you! This was just an example and the actual code is a little different but I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ORDER BY` clause check first if there is an exact match or (if you want it) `keywords` starts with `'$query'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE keywords LIKE '%$query%' 
ORDER BY keywords = '$query' DESC, -- 1st keywords with exact match
         keywords LIKE '$query%' DESC, -- 2nd keywords which start with '$query'    
         likes DESC -- 3d likes
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Also, if you want to treat words that *start* with the search term with higher priority, you might take a look at the [`POSITION`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-position-function.php) function, whose result can be added to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @at54321 there is no need for a function in this case. LIKE can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE keywords LIKE '$query')
union
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE keywords LIKE '%$query%' order by likes desc LIMIT 50);
```

With first query you get the exact match and with second, others matches order by likes.